# DevOps Windows Service Manager - install top shelf service where the name contains spaces

Tags: azure-pipelines, topshelf

I'm using Windows Service manager within a devops release pipeline to install a top shelf service.

[image]

If the Service Name is "My Service" it fails

However, if I change it to "MyService" it works

[image]

You can install top shelf services using the command line with space and you could also do it in the old release manager.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: hi sun, any update?

Comment: I used a different task in the end

Comment: You could share your solution as a post and mark it as answer to benefit more developers.

Answer (score 0):

From the resource code of this task, [Windows Service Manager](https://github.com/Dejulia489/WindowsServiceManager/blob/master/WindowsServiceManager/WindowsServiceManagerV4/task.json#:%7E:text=%22name%22%3A%20%22ServiceName,the%20deployment%20group%20target.%22).

> "name": "ServiceName",
>
> "type": "string",
>
> "label": "Service name",
>
> "defaultValue": "",
>
> "required": true,
>
> "helpMarkDown": "The exact name of the windows service installed on the deployment group target."

I suppose you need to validate the service name installed on your target machine before you input it in the task field.